# Call a jquery function at the end of video in flowplayer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, flowplayer

From 2 days i am stuck with an issue with flowplayer i am unable to call external jquery function at any events even in the starting or ending or video , how to go forward. i am literally pulling my hair ,please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script language="javascript">
// our custom configuration is given in third argument
flowplayer("playerContainer", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf",{
clip: {
  onBeforeFinish: function () {
    this.getPlugin('content').setHtml('onBeforeFinish event fired');
  }
},
plugins: {
  content: {
    url: 'flowplayer.content-3.2.8.swf'
  }
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Pleas check the below fiddle , i have tried but it is not working ..:(
http://jsfiddle.net/vamsikrishna981/VgM4D/1/

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your application in the chrome console? (F12)

Comment: Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead. 
Above error i am getting

Comment: Hi, when i am checking in jsfiddle it is working fine but when i am seeing in my system i am unable to see the changes(HTML adding)